# silverlight configured to use a proxy server

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-3.0

If I use silverlight on a web page, can it be configured so that any web requests within a silverlight app are routed through a proxy server even if the web browser is not configured to use a web browser.

Comment: If the application is yours, you control the web requests, so you are free to send them to whatever domain you want, including a proxy, aren't you? or do you mean hijacking the requests coming from an app you don't have the source code for?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the client networking stack. Browser stack uses browser proxy info (you don't need it), client stack uses OS proxy info.

This sample tells Silverlight that all calls to addresses that begin with “http://” should use the client stack rather than the browser stack.

```
HttpWebRequest.RegisterPrefix("http://", WebRequestCreator.ClientHttp);
```

More info: http://www.wintellect.com/cs/blogs/jprosise/archive/2009/10/14/silverlight-3-s-new-client-networking-stack.aspx

Comment: Thank you for your answer its appreciated